# dependent: :delete_all association not deleting associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I can't understand why my **dependent: option** isn't deleting my associations...

[Rails api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) say this:

"Delete or destroy?

has_many and has_and_belongs_to_many associations have the methods destroy, delete, destroy_all and delete_all.

...

For has_many, destroy and destroy_all will always call the destroy method of the record(s) being removed so that callbacks are run. **However delete and delete_all will either do the deletion according to the strategy specified by the :dependent option**, or if no :dependent option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. The default strategy is to do nothing (leave the foreign keys with the parent ids set), except for has_many :through, where the default strategy is delete_all (delete the join records, without running their callbacks)."

Okay, so why isn't my **...delete...do[ing] the deletion according to the strategy specified by the :dependent option**?

I have a UserProfile model that has a *has_many* relationship with my CustomSkill model; my CustomSkill model *belongs_to* a UserProfile. I set up *dependent: :delete_all* on the association that my UserProfile model has with CustomSkill, but when I delete a UserProfile, the associated CustomSkills fail to get deleted.

P.S. If I use *destroy* when deleting my UserProfile, it seems to work, but I am trying to avoid using callbacks, which delete/delete_all is supposed to do (if I'm understanding 'callbacks' correctly, running rails model callbacks when a delete takes place, because I don't have them coded anyhow).

What am I missing here?

```
# Controller#destroy
def destroy
   UserProfile.find_by_id(destroy_params).delete
   redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile deleted'
end

# UserProfile model
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :custom_skills, dependent: :delete_all
end

# CustomSkill model
class CustomSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user_profile
end

# Schema.rb
create_table "user_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "type"
    t.string   "profile_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "custom_skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_profile_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` does not trigger callbacks (including `dependent: :delete_all`). So when you say

```
UserProfile.find_by_id(destroy_params).delete
```

the callbacks for UserProfile are not run (including the callback to delete all associated CustomSkills).

To run callbacks (including `dependent: :delete_all`), use `destroy`.

```
UserProfile.find_by_id(destroy_params).destroy
```

Comment: I had been confounded by this problem for hours. I read a bunch of comments saying similar things, but your explanation about the callback was the clearest and I got my issue resolved. Thanks so much!